# Python: csv to pickle representation, back to csv messes with file content

Tags: python, csv, pickle

I am trying to pickle a csv file and then turn its pickled representation back into a csv file.

This is the code I came up with:

```
from pathlib import Path
import pickle, csv

csvFilePath = Path('/path/to/file.csv')

pathToSaveTo = Path('/path/to/newFile.csv')

csvFile = open(csvFilePath, 'r')
f = csvFile.read() 
csvFile.close() 

f_pickled = pickle.dumps(f) 


f_unpickled = pickle.loads(f_pickled) 

#save unpickled csv file
new_csvFile = open(pathToSaveTo, 'w')
csvWriter = csv.writer(new_csvFile)
csvWriter.writerow(f_unpickled)
new_csvFile.close()
```

newFile.csv is created however there are two problems with its content:

1. There is now a comma between every character.
2. There is now a pair of quotation marks after every line.
   [image: screenshot of file.csv]

[image: screenshot of newFile.csv]

What would I have to change about my code to get an exact copy of file.csv?

Comment: Your input file doesn't seem to be comma-separated

Comment: While that is true putting a comma after each 'test' did produce similar results. Since I only have one column in each row I assumed it wasn't necessary to put a comma after each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are reading the raw text of the file, with `f = csvFile.read()` then, on writting, you are feeding the data, which is a single lump of text, all in a single string, though a CSV `writer` object. The CSV `writer` will see the string as an iterable, and write each of the iterable elements in a CSV cell. Then, there is no data for a second row, and the process ends.

The pickle `dumps` and `loads` you perform is just a no-operation: nothing happens there, and if there were any issue, it would rather be due to some unpickleable object reference in the object you are passing to `dumps`: you'd get an exception, and not differing data when `loads` is called.

Now, without telling why you want to do this, and what intermediate steps you hav planned for the data, it is hard to tell you: you are performing two non-operations: reading a file, pickling and unpickling its contents, and writting those contents back to disk.

At which point do you need these data structured as rows, or as CSV cells? Just apply the proper transforms where you need it, and you are done.

If you want the whole "do nothing" cycle going through actual having the CSV data separated in different elements in Python you can perform:

```
from pathlib import Path
import pickle, csv

csvFilePath = Path('file.csv')

pathToSaveTo = Path('newFile.csv')

data = list(csv.reader(open(csvFilePath))) 
# ^consumes all iterations of the reader: each iteration is a row, composed of a list where each cell value is a list elemnt
pickled_data = pickle.dumps(data)
restored_data = pickle.loads(pickled_data)
csv.writer(open(pathToSaveTo, "wt")).writerows(restored_data)
```

Perceive as in this snippet the data is read through csv.reader, not directly. Wrapping it in a list call causes all rows to be read and transformed in list items - because the reader is a lazy iterator otherwise (and it would not be pickeable, as one of the attributs it depends for its state is an open file)

Comment: My original idea was to send a csv file via sockets from a client to a server. Since pickling a python object is said to keep the objects structure I thought it'd be easier to send the pickled representation of the csv file than a list of rows.

Comment: nice. So,  "ickled_data" can be transported in this way. And so is the original `f` variable in your code -although you'd have to convert it to bytes (with f.encode('utf-8") s -pickling may be more convenient. Just take care that sending a large amount of data (sveral hundrde kbytes in this case) through a socket will require you to split the information in various datagrams

Comment: TL;DR: use a higher level protocol that will take care of tht for you: sockets are too low level for this, and ou will hav to reinvent some wheels;

Comment: Ah I see. However if I have to resort to sending a list of all rows is there any benefit to pickling it before sending? As you can probably guess from my original question I'm still a beginner so I'm trying to learn the basics. Out of curiosity and for further studies what would be an appropriate higher level protocol?

Comment: Yes - so, "beginner learning the basics" should not try to "create a new a protocol for rpc over raw sockets" :-)  . You can make use of "celery" - it will tak care of data serialization and task distribution for workers, all in the background, and is extremely well tested for production. There are intermediate protocols there, but celery would be both easy enough and production ready.

Comment: https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/getting-started/introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is in how you're attempting to write the CSV file, the pickling and unpickling is fine. If you compare f with f_unpickled:

```
if f==f_unpickled:
    print("Same")
```

This printed in my case. If you print the type, you'll see there's both strings.

The better option is to follow the [document style](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) and write each row one at a time rather than putting the entire string in including new lines. Something like this:

```
from pathlib import Path
import pickle, csv

csvFilePath = Path('file.csv')

pathToSaveTo = Path('newFile.csv')

rows = []
csvFile = open(csvFilePath, 'r')
with open(csvFilePath, 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:
        rows.append(row)

# pickle and unpickle        
rows_pickled = pickle.dumps(rows) 
rows_unpickled = pickle.loads(rows_pickled) 
if rows==rows_unpickled:
    print("Same")

#save unpickled csv file
with open(pathToSaveTo, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    csvWriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for row in rows_unpickled:
        csvWriter.writerow(row)
```

This worked when I tested it--albeit it would take more finagling with line separators to get no empty line at the end.

Comment: actually, there is no problem in reading the file in one big gulp - th problem is the file is being read as "raw text", and being written back via a `csv.writer` object, which will then treat each row in a single CSV cell

Comment: Ah, right; the original example is reading the file contents directly rather than using the reader and then the writer is just converting the raw text (if I swap out the reader loop there for the original reading code, it prints every single character on a new line, which is interesting). Still, for reading in an entire CSV file and writing out an entire CSV file, using the actual reader and writer methods on a per-row basis seems obvious.